# compare values in two xmls in wso2 esb sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to compare two xmls in a sequence and store the number of matches in a variable. can this be achieved through sequence.

for example first sequence will be:

```
<employees>
    <employee><id>1</id><name>abc</name></employee>
    <employee><id>2</id><name>def</name></employee>
    <employee><id>3</id><name>ghi</name></employee>
</employees>
```

second xml

```
<employees>
    <employee><id>1</id><name>abc</name></employee>
    <employee><id>3</id><name>ghi</name></employee>
</employees>
```

when I compare these two xmls I need to get a count value of 2. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this [class mediators.](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/12/writing-custom-class-mediator-in.html) Write your logic in your java class and store the property in synapse context in your custom class.